# Приоритет операций при использовании указателей на структуры

Tags: c, указатели, структуры

Изучаю приоритеты операций при обращении к полям структур по указателю. Есть такой код из Кернигана и Ритчи:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct my {
        int x;
        char *str;
};

int main() {
        struct my st = {1, "abc"};
        struct my *p = &st;

        printf("x = %d, s = %s\n", p->x, p->str);
        printf(*p->str);
        return 0;
}
```

В строке `printf(*p->str);` происходит сегфолт. Почему?

В книге не дана структура, над которой проводятся эти опыты, я ее придумал сам, глядя на то, как она используется. Должно быть так: приоритет у стрелки выше, чем у операции разыменовывания, поэтому сначала получаем указатель `str` на строку `"abc"`. Потом этот указатель на строку разыменовываем, получаем данные и печатаем их.

Comment: А вам компилятор предупреждений не дает ? printf первым параметром берет указатель на строку, а вы ему подсовываете в качестве такого указателя само значение. я бы на месте компилятора ругался бы благим матом на такое

Comment: Не вспомнил о том, что принимает printf. Тогда понятно, в чем дело. Хотел каким-нибудь образом убедиться, что эта конструкция работает так, как описано, и вывести данные.

Comment: Если бы у * приоритет был выше, то компилятор бы ругался на стрелку, после разименованного указателя на структуру

Comment: Вы хотели сделать `printf("%c\n",*p->str)`...

Answer (score 1):

Всё банальнее. `p->str` это и есть указатель на строку "abc", через указатель на её первый символ. Поэтому `printf(p->str)` сработает. А вот `*p->str` становится равным числу 97 (код "a"), и поэтому printf пытается напечатать что-то начиная с адреса 97, который обычно вместе с несколькими первыми страницами запрещён для доступа.

(А если 64-разрядная архитектура, то printf ожидает 8-байтный указатель, а `*p->str` будет 4-байтным числом, то есть будет передано нечто из 97 и 4 байт мусора. Тоже непредсказуемый результат...)

И ещё - печатать произвольную строку в printf надо через `printf("%s", str)`, а не `printf(str)`, кроме случаев, когда гарантируется, что str не будет содержать '%' (и эта гарантия на все версии вперёд, так что лучше сразу поберечься и поставить %s).